# Is there a CSS class or so for a pressed state of an INPUT submit?

Tags: css, submit

When a `INPUT` `submit` element is pressed, then it looks "pressed". Is there a CSS class or so for a pressed state of an `INPUT` `submit`?
Unfortunately, the `:active` class like

```
input:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

does not do a proper job, since it stays active when "pressed" even though the pointer is no more over the submit.

Is there a way to get this done with pure CSS or do I need JavaScript?

#### [edit]

Look at a normal (unstyled) submit button (http://jsfiddle.net/j39nw/). If you press it, then it looks "lowered". Now, hold the mouse button pressed and move the mouse pointer outside of the button. As you can see, the "lowered" effect vanishes as soon as the pointer leaves the button even though it is still pressed. With the classes `active` or `focus` you cannot get such an effect, since it will still look pressed even though it is no more.

Comment: will `input:focus` do?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, `input:focus` does not do the trick, since it stays in the "pressed" state even though the mouse button is no more pressed. So in a way it is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing this with css, but if you check the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`state with jquery you can add a class and apply the focus to that class.

```
$('.input').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
    $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
        $('.input').blur();
    });
});
```

EDIT:
When the mouse is moved out of the element the element loses focus. When it is moved back in while the mouse button is still held down, the element regains focus.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/RJvLE/4/

EDIT#2:
As @Daniel suggests in the comments the code gets a bit easier when using `active` instead of `focus`, cf. http://jsfiddle.net/Rw7F4/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Interesting that CSS fails with such apparently standard tasks. However, your jQuery code does not do it properly either, since the input-submit will look pressed whenever it is focused and the pointer is over it irrespective of any mouse button being pressed. But a button should look pressed only when pressed.

Comment: I have added a `.blur()` on `mouseout` to remove the behaviour you described: http://jsfiddle.net/RJvLE/3/
I don't think this is really a css issue but the element does not lose the focus state when you drag the mouse away from the button (although it does not get clicked).

Comment: Now it does not get pressed anymore when the mouse is pressed over the submit and held, moved out and moved in again.

Comment: Ah ok. I think I understood now. Please check this v4 of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RJvLE/4/

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Here is another one based on your solution that apparently works and uses `active` instead of `focus` and is a bit less complicated: http://jsfiddle.net/Rw7F4/.

Comment: I was so focused on `focus` ... ;)

Comment: Edit your answer if you feel it's worth it. :)

Answer (score 0):

`input[type="submit"]:active{
    background: red;
}`

It works, check this demo

http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/RJvLE/

Comment: Thanks. I checked it, but it does not work. Press the submit button, hold the mouse button pressed, move the mouse pointer outside of the button. The button is still red, signaling a pressed state. But it is not. If you release the mouse button, the submit is not clicked.

Comment: When you release the mouse from submit button, its active state will also gone. If you still want to appear it as red then you can use jquery for that. Try this demo (http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/RJvLE/1/)

Comment: No that is not what I intended. Sorry for not making myself clear enough. I added an [edit] to my question to explain it better.